# Solving an Integral equation

Tags: equation-solving

I would like to solve the equation
$$\frac{2}{p}\int_0^1((1-u)^{1-p}+u^{1-p})^{\frac{1}{p}}\text{d}u=42$$ for p numerically.

I tried

```
NSolve[2/p*Integrate[(u^(1 - p) + (1 - u)^(1 - p))^(1/p), {u, 0, 1}] == 42, p]
```

and

```
FindRoot[2/p*Integrate[(u^(1 - p) + (1 - u)^(1 - p))^(1/p), {u, 0, 1}] == 42, {p, 0.08}]
```

and

```
h[p_?NumericQ] := 2/p*NIntegrate[((1 - u)^(1 - p) + u^(1 - p))^(1/p), {u, 0, 1}]
FindRoot[h[p] == 42, {p, 0, 1}]
```

(I know the answer is approximately 0.0804670), however I still would like to know how it is computed.

In both cases, I received errors:

```
NSolve::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to NSolve
```

and

```
GCD::exact: "Argument 0.92` in GCD[0,0.92] is not an exact number.
FactorSquareFree::lrgexp: Exponent is out of bounds for function FactorSquareFree.
GCD::exact: "Argument 0.9195355178111501` in GCD[0,0.919536] is not an exact number.
```

How do I solve this equation? Preferably with as little Integral evaluations, because they are horribly slow.

**EDIT** nevermind, sorry. There was a typo in the third try. Thank you for your time >_<

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`Integrate` evaluations are slow, but `NIntegrate` are reasonably quick.  You'll need to define a function `f` that is valid only for numeric arguments.

```
f[p_?NumericQ] := 2/p*NIntegrate[(u^(1 - p) + (1 - u)^(1 - p))^(1/p), {u, 0, 1}];
FindRoot[f[p] == 42, {p, 0.08}]

(* Out: {p -> 0.0804672} *)
```

Comment: Oh I tried something similar aswell... I got a bunch of Infinite Expression errors however? I will add that to the OP

Comment: I found my typo in the third try (I thought that would not work, because it instantly threw dozens of errors at me)
How do I improve the precision? AccuracyGoal and PrecisionGoal do not change the output?